# Not able to open a url with a PDF

Tags: python, pypdf

I am getting the following error

> IOError:[Errno socket error] EOF occurred in violation of protocol
>   (_ssl.c:590).

I am trying to download a pdf using this link:
url = https://fch.webcvo.net/TempFiles/UploadImageFiles/Sync_Doc/12228-7138-578-03-09-2016-13-16-27.pdf

Any way I can troubleshoot or get around this?